# Sharepoint calendar Restrict event end time

Tags: calendar

We have a sharepoint calendar at my organiztion that users add events to in order to reserve certain rooms for events. I need to find a way to make is so that they can not enter events that start or run past 2:30. Like something like make it so that the end time field will only go up to 2:30.

It would also be useful to have it pop an error with a link to a different calendar if they did want to enter an event that went past this time, (we have a different calendar for use after 2:30) But thats more icing on the cake. If I could get the latest end tiem option to be 2:30, it would save me much headache.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Robert, 
I'm not sure if you've already found an answer to this, but I found a site that has a great program (already built and downloadable for free) that will help with this. Here is the site: http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/spjs-resource-management-no-more-double-booking/
It was developed to prevent double bookings on calendars, but also has a component to only allow appointments to be booked at certain times.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

1. SharePoint 2010 comes with a new feature available as part of Group
   Work Feature which proposes a new column doing actually the
   double-booking check in your Calendar. You could try this directly
   on a Group Work Site,  there the calendar is actually already
   enabled for that.
2. There is a feature new in SP 2010 that also enables Column and List Validation formulas which could be used to add more business rules to your lists.